# Why does my table sorter work only on some columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, tablesorter

I have a table sorter function that only works on some columns and only sorts the first column correctly when I click whatever  I have. However, if I click the first and last , it sorts the table in an incomprehensible manner.

I am a newbie in javascript and even though I was able to fix a couple of behaviours, I can't get it to work 100% properly.

This is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m_tibo/0t83no14/4/

And this is my function:

```
// TABLESORTER
function accordionTable(i, elem) {
  var table = $(elem),
    tbody = table.find('tbody'),
    th_index = 0,
    th_sortType = "int";

  function mapTDs(i, elem) {
    var txt = $("td", elem).eq(th_index).text();
    $(elem).attr("data-sort", txt);
  }

  function sortAsc(a, b) {
    var aData = $(a).attr("data-sort"),
      bData = $(b).attr("data-sort");
    if (th_sortType == "string") {
      return +bData < +aData ? 1 : -1; // Integer
    } else {
      return bData < aData ? 1 : -1; // String or else
    }
  }

  //header sort
  table.on("click", "th", function() {
    th_sortType = $(this).data('sort');
    th_index = $(this).index();
    tbody = table.find('tbody').each(mapTDs);
    tbody.sort(sortAsc).detach().appendTo(table);
  });
}

$('table').each(accordionTable);
```

What I expect from the function is to sort the table on each column both ascending and descending.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The way the HTML is set up, you'll need to use the [sort tbodies widget](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-sort-tbodies.html); but in your case, I think you can keep all rows in the same `tbody` and set the child rows class ([demo](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-child-rows-filtered.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one:
https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/wty134u7/

```
    $('table').tablesorter({

// *** APPEARANCE ***
// Add a theme - try 'blackice', 'blue', 'dark', 'default'
//  'dropbox', 'green', 'grey' or 'ice'
// to use 'bootstrap' or 'jui', you'll need to add the "uitheme"
// widget and also set it to the same name
// this option only adds a table class name "tablesorter-{theme}"
theme: 'blackice',

// fix the column widths
widthFixed: false,

// Show an indeterminate timer icon in the header when the table
// is sorted or filtered
showProcessing: false,

// header layout template (HTML ok); {content} = innerHTML,
// {icon} = <i/> (class from cssIcon)
headerTemplate: '{content}',

// return the modified template string
onRenderTemplate: null, // function(index, template){ return template; },

// called after each header cell is rendered, use index to target the column
// customize header HTML
onRenderHeader: function (index) {
    // the span wrapper is added by default
    $(this).find('div.tablesorter-header-inner').addClass('roundedCorners');
},

// *** FUNCTIONALITY ***
// prevent text selection in header
cancelSelection: true,

// other options: "ddmmyyyy" & "yyyymmdd"
dateFormat: "mmddyyyy",

// The key used to select more than one column for multi-column
// sorting.
sortMultiSortKey: "shiftKey",

// key used to remove sorting on a column
sortResetKey: 'ctrlKey',

// false for German "1.234.567,89" or French "1 234 567,89"
usNumberFormat: true,

// If true, parsing of all table cell data will be delayed
// until the user initializes a sort
delayInit: false,

// if true, server-side sorting should be performed because
// client-side sorting will be disabled, but the ui and events
// will still be used.
serverSideSorting: false,

// *** SORT OPTIONS ***
// These are detected by default,
// but you can change or disable them
// these can also be set using data-attributes or class names
headers: {
    // set "sorter : false" (no quotes) to disable the column
    0: {
        sorter: "text"
    },
    1: {
        sorter: "text"
    },
    3: {
        sorter: "digit"
    }
},

// ignore case while sorting
ignoreCase: true,

// forces the user to have this/these column(s) sorted first
sortForce: null,
// initial sort order of the columns, example sortList: [[0,0],[1,0]],
// [[columnIndex, sortDirection], ... ]
sortList: [
    [0, 0],
    [1, 0],
    [2, 0]
],
// default sort that is added to the end of the users sort
// selection.
sortAppend: null,

// starting sort direction "asc" or "desc"
sortInitialOrder: "asc",

// Replace equivalent character (accented characters) to allow
// for alphanumeric sorting
sortLocaleCompare: false,

// third click on the header will reset column to default - unsorted
sortReset: false,

// restart sort to "sortInitialOrder" when clicking on previously
// unsorted columns
sortRestart: false,

// sort empty cell to bottom, top, none, zero
emptyTo: "bottom",

// sort strings in numerical column as max, min, top, bottom, zero
stringTo: "max",

// extract text from the table - this is how is
// it done by default
textExtraction: {
    0: function (node) {
        return $(node).text();
    },
    1: function (node) {
        return $(node).text();
    }
},

// use custom text sorter
// function(a,b){ return a.sort(b); } // basic sort
textSorter: null,

// *** WIDGETS ***

// apply widgets on tablesorter initialization
initWidgets: true,

// include zebra and any other widgets, options:
// 'columns', 'filter', 'stickyHeaders' & 'resizable'
// 'uitheme' is another widget, but requires loading
// a different skin and a jQuery UI theme.
widgets: ['zebra', 'columns'],

widgetOptions: {

    // zebra widget: adding zebra striping, using content and
    // default styles - the ui css removes the background
    // from default even and odd class names included for this
    // demo to allow switching themes
    // [ "even", "odd" ]
    zebra: [
        "ui-widget-content even",
        "ui-state-default odd"],

    // uitheme widget: * Updated! in tablesorter v2.4 **
    // Instead of the array of icon class names, this option now
    // contains the name of the theme. Currently jQuery UI ("jui")
    // and Bootstrap ("bootstrap") themes are supported. To modify
    // the class names used, extend from the themes variable
    // look for the "$.extend($.tablesorter.themes.jui" code below
    uitheme: 'jui',

    // columns widget: change the default column class names
    // primary is the 1st column sorted, secondary is the 2nd, etc
    columns: [
        "primary",
        "secondary",
        "tertiary"],

    // columns widget: If true, the class names from the columns
    // option will also be added to the table tfoot.
    columns_tfoot: true,

    // columns widget: If true, the class names from the columns
    // option will also be added to the table thead.
    columns_thead: true,

    // filter widget: If there are child rows in the table (rows with
    // class name from "cssChildRow" option) and this option is true
    // and a match is found anywhere in the child row, then it will make
    // that row visible; default is false
    filter_childRows: false,

    // filter widget: If true, a filter will be added to the top of
    // each table column.
    filter_columnFilters: true,

    // filter widget: css class applied to the table row containing the
    // filters & the inputs within that row
    filter_cssFilter: "tablesorter-filter",

    // filter widget: Customize the filter widget by adding a select
    // dropdown with content, custom options or custom filter functions

    filter_functions: null,

    // filter widget: Set this option to true to hide the filter row
    // initially. The rows is revealed by hovering over the filter
    // row or giving any filter input/select focus.
    filter_hideFilters: false,

    // filter widget: Set this option to false to keep the searches
    // case sensitive
    filter_ignoreCase: true,

    // filter widget: jQuery selector string of an element used to
    // reset the filters.
    filter_reset: null,

    // Delay in milliseconds before the filter widget starts searching;
    // This option prevents searching for every character while typing
    // and should make searching large tables faster.
    filter_searchDelay: 300,

    // Set this option to true if filtering is performed on the server-side.
    filter_serversideFiltering: false,

    // filter widget: Set this option to true to use the filter to find
    // text from the start of the column. So typing in "a" will find
    // "albert" but not "frank", both have a's; default is false
    filter_startsWith: false,

    // filter widget: If true, ALL filter searches will only use parsed
    // data. To only use parsed data in specific columns, set this option
    // to false and add class name "filter-parsed" to the header
    filter_useParsedData: false,

    // Resizable widget: If this option is set to false, resized column
    // widths will not be saved. Previous saved values will be restored
    // on page reload
    resizable: true,

    // saveSort widget: If this option is set to false, new sorts will
    // not be saved. Any previous saved sort will be restored on page
    // reload.
    saveSort: true,

    // stickyHeaders widget: css class name applied to the sticky header
    stickyHeaders: "tablesorter-stickyHeader"

},

// *** CALLBACKS ***
// function called after tablesorter has completed initialization
initialized: function (table) {},

// *** CSS CLASS NAMES ***
tableClass: 'tablesorter',
cssAsc: "tablesorter-headerSortUp",
cssDesc: "tablesorter-headerSortDown",
cssHeader: "tablesorter-header",
cssHeaderRow: "tablesorter-headerRow",
cssIcon: "tablesorter-icon",
cssChildRow: "tablesorter-childRow",
cssInfoBlock: "tablesorter-infoOnly",
cssProcessing: "tablesorter-processing",

// *** SELECTORS ***
// jQuery selectors used to find the header cells.
selectorHeaders: '> thead th, > thead td',

// jQuery selector of content within selectorHeaders
// that is clickable to trigger a sort.
selectorSort: "th, td",

// rows with this class name will be removed automatically
// before updating the table cache - used by "update",
// "addRows" and "appendCache"
selectorRemove: "tr.remove-me",

// *** DEBUGING ***
// send messages to console
debug: false
```

}).tablesorterPager({

```
container: $(".pager"),
ajaxUrl: null,

ajaxProcessing: function(ajax) {
    if (ajax && ajax.hasOwnProperty('data')) {

        return [ajax.data, ajax.total_rows];
    }
},

   output: '{startRow} to {endRow} ({totalRows})',


updateArrows: true,
page: 0,
size: 10,
fixedHeight: true,
removeRows: false,
cssNext: '.next',
// previous page arrow
cssPrev: '.prev',
// go to first page arrow
cssFirst: '.first',
// go to last page arrow
cssLast: '.last',
// select dropdown to allow choosing a page
cssGoto: '.gotoPage',
// location of where the "output" is displayed
cssPageDisplay: '.pagedisplay',
// dropdown that sets the "size" option
cssPageSize: '.pagesize',
// class added to arrows when at the extremes 
// (i.e. prev/first arrows are "disabled" when on the first page)
// Note there is no period "." in front of this class name
cssDisabled: 'disabled'

});

// Extend the themes to change any of the default class names ** NEW **
$.extend($.tablesorter.themes.jui, {
// change default jQuery uitheme icons - find the full list of icons
// here: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ (hover over them for their name)
table: 'ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all', // table classes
header: 'ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-state-default', // header classes
icons: 'ui-icon', // icon class added to the <i> in the header
sortNone: 'ui-icon-carat-2-n-s',
sortAsc: 'ui-icon-carat-1-n',
sortDesc: 'ui-icon-carat-1-s',
active: 'ui-state-active', // applied when column is sorted
hover: 'ui-state-hover', // hover class
filterRow: '',
even: 'ui-widget-content', // even row zebra striping
odd: 'ui-state-default' // odd row zebra striping
});

It works perfectly
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. Would this work also if each <tr> had a hidden and collapsible <tr>?

Comment: why you want to add hidden <TR>. If the value is hidden then it will sort according to the values. But the hidden field is not visible to us. The filtered data will again look improper.

Comment: In my original table, each <tr> has another row hidden with some details. That's why I'd need that, as in the fiddle example I posted.

Comment: you had hidden values in column or row??

Comment: Rows. If you click on each row, they open up

Comment: it should work with the data available in the table.